# How to access admin panel completely?

Tags: admin, admin-panel, access

My website developer gave me a limited access to Magento admin-panel. Now he left the field without giving me the full access.

Help me access admin completely and access site resource.

Comment: Have you database access?

Comment: I guess you must have cpanel access of your hosting so it easy to get other access from there.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to database ? What can I do from there ? I contact the hosting company, they talled about Phpmyadmin and that I have to change the Sql scrypt, but well as I am not an IT guy and did want to do something wrong! Is there any other easier solution as I just want to get the username and password that my developer were using!

Answer (score 0):

With ssh access you can create new admin user. Just run following in magento root and then you can use login

Login: newadmin

Password :newadminpassword12:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="newadmin" --admin-password=:newadminpassword12: --admin-email="admin@newadmin.com" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin"
```

Comment: but can you just please tell me how to use the SSH access as I am not an It guy and do know and understand everything easily!

Comment: That may really depend on many things. Basically your store is hosted somewhere, do you pay for the hosting? If yes then i would recommend to write to your hosting providers support, explain them the situation and ask them to resolve it (perhaps post link to this question and ask them to create new account for you). Any half decent hosting company will do this for you. If you have no control over the hosting then it may be more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Database admin user name:: you need just admin User name and below changes
Magento2 Bypass admin

```
vendor\Magento\module-user\Model\User.php :
```

**find** 
`public function verifyIdentity()` set `return true;` to bypass admin.

Ex-

```
public function verifyIdentity($password)
    {
       /*  $result = false;
        if ($this->_encryptor->validateHash($password, $this->getPassword())) {
            if ($this->getIsActive() != '1') {
                throw new AuthenticationException(
                    __('You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.')
                );
            }
            if (!$this->hasAssigned2Role($this->getId())) {
                throw new AuthenticationException(__('You need more permissions to access this.'));
            }
            $result = true;
        } */
        return true;
    }
```

after bypass `cache clear` and enter the name and any password it's working.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just, can you tell me how to check in the database the admin user name ?